# Can't add SOE extension

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

My SOE extension crashed. Now it does not appear in extension list, but does so in Capitabilities of a service. Services with it give error on run. When I try to add it anew to the server, I get 
"An extension with name 'xxx' is already registered for service type 'MapServer'"
error.

ArcGIS Installation 10.1. To default location.

Note: Solutions I got on the internet:
      a. Restart ArcGIS Server from Task Manager( restarted many times everything that can be restarted -> no effect )
      b. Remove and re-install ArcMap Server ( can't do it now, may be as last resort)

Comment: I had this happen once; I called Tech Support, and they told me which file to alter. It was years ago, though, so it will take a while to track it down. In the meantime you can **edit** the question to include the version of ArcGIS and the exact install location.

Comment: In my Linux 10.2.2 install, there's a file called `bin/ServerTypesExt.dat`.  It's an XML file.  Try removing the entire `<ExtensionType file="your-soe-name-here.soe">` block (to the line above `</ExtensionTypes>`).  If that doesn't work, either reinstall or wait for Tech Support on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows open  C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\bin\ServerTypesExt.dat and remove references to it :

```
<ExtensionType file="mysoe.soe">
    <Name>MySOE</Name>
    <DisplayName>MySOE</DisplayName>
    <CLSID>my.soe</CLSID>
    <Description>MySOE description</Description>
    <MaxUploadFileSize>-1</MaxUploadFileSize>
    <AllowedUploadFileTypes/>
    <Properties/>
    <Info>
      <DefaultWebCapabilities/>
      <AllWebCapabilities/>
      <hasManagerPropertiesConfigurationPane>false</hasManagerPropertiesConfigurationPane>
      <SupportsSOAP>false</SupportsSOAP>
      <SupportsREST>true</SupportsREST>
    </Info>
    <Resources>
      <WSDL/>
    </Resources>
  </ExtensionType>
</ExtensionTypes>
```